# incorrect output when using uint64_t

Tags: c, types, output

Create   functionpoint_add() implementing   point   adding   operation.   Input parameters are 2 distinct points. Function returns new calculated point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


typedef struct {
    uint64_t x;
    uint64_t y;
} point;


point point_add(point P, point Q){
    point R;
    R.x = 0;
    R.y = 0;

    if(P.x == Q.x && P.y == Q.y) return R;
    
    double s = ((double)(P.y - Q.y))/((double)(P.x-Q.x));
    R.x=s*s-P.x-Q.x;
    R.y=s*(P.x-Q.x)-P.y;

return R;
}

int main(){ 
  point A = {1, 2};
  point B = {3, 4};
  point C = {5, 6};
  point D;

  // Test case 1: A + B
  D = point_add(A, B);
  printf("(%lu, %lu) + (%lu, %lu) = (%lu, %lu)\n", A.x, A.y, B.x, B.y, D.x, D.y);
  // Expected output: (1, 2) + (3, 4) = (2, 3)

  // Test case 2: B + C
  D = point_add(B, C);
  printf("(%lu, %lu) + (%lu, %lu) = (%lu, %lu)\n", B.x, B.y, C.x, C.y, D.x, D.y);
  // Expected output: (3, 4) + (5, 6) = (-11, -30)

  // Test case 3: A + A
  D = point_add(A, A);
  printf("(%lu, %lu) + (%lu, %lu) = (%lu, %lu)\n", A.x, A.y, A.x, A.y, D.x, D.y);
  // Expected output: (1, 2) + (1, 2) = (0, 0)

    return 0;
}
```

but i have output like that

```
(1, 2) + (3, 4) = (18446744073709551613, 9223372036854775808)
(3, 4) + (5, 6) = (18446744073709551609, 9223372036854775808)
(1, 2) + (1, 2) = (0, 0)
```

last case is correct, but idk how to fix first two

rewrite a code into this, bit it didn't solve the problem

```
point point_add(point P, point Q){
    point R;

    uint16_t s;
    s = (P.y - Q.y) / (P.x - Q.x);

    if((P.x == Q.x && P.y == Q.y)|| (P.x == Q.x && P.x != Q.x)|| s<0){ R.x = 0; R.y = 0;}
    
    R.x=s*s-P.x-Q.x;
    R.y=s*(P.x-Q.x)-P.y;

return R;
}

int main(){ 
  point A = {1, 2};
  point B = {3, 4};
  point C = {5, 6};
  point D;

  D = point_add(A, B);
  printf("%" PRIu64 ",%" PRIu64"\n", D.x, D.y);
  // Expected output: (1, 2) + (3, 4) = (2, 3)

  // Test case 3: A + A
  D = point_add(A, A);
  printf("%" PRIu64 ",%" PRIu64"\n", D.x, D.y);
  // Expected output: (1, 2) + (1, 2) = (0, 0) 

    return 0;
}
```

but output changed to this

```
18446744073709551613,18446744073709551612
Floating point exception
```

Comment: `%lu` --> `%" PRIu64 "`

Comment: The type `uint64_t` is commonly an alias for `unsigned long long`. For which you need to use the `%llu` forma. But it's better to use the correct [format macro constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_macro_constants) instead. Like `printf("(%" PRIu64 ", %" PRIu64 ")", A.x, A.y)`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: On a side note: if P.x == Q.x and P.y != Q.y you will end up with some nasty results

Comment: Do you mean "point" in the geometric sense?  I don't know what it means to "add" two points in that sense.  I do know what it means to add two *vectors*, but it's not what you've implemented.

Comment: Currently we can only try to guess from your wrong code what function `point_add` is supposed to calculate. Please [edit] your question and add some background information: What do you mean with "point adding operation"? If possible add a link to a description, e.g. on Wikipedia. Assuming you mean a point in geometric sense, you are limited to the first quadrant, because your structure can only hold non-negative values. (as others already wrote). For easier debugging, write the calculation in multiple lines, store intermediate values in additional variables and check the values in a debugger.

Answer (score 4):

uint64_t is unsigned

```
double s = ((double)(P.y - Q.y))/((double)(P.x-Q.x));
```

Might end up negative, which when assigned to an unsigned type will give some very large numbers.

You probably need to cater for this in the code somehow.  As a test, can you change uint64_t to int64_t and see what you get.

ADDED 31st Mar 2023

In your re-worked question you have this:

```
point point_add(point P, point Q){
    point R;

    uint16_t s;
    s = (P.y - Q.y) / (P.x - Q.x);

    if((P.x == Q.x && P.y == Q.y)|| (P.x == Q.x && P.x != Q.x)|| s<0){ R.x = 0; R.y = 0;}
    
    R.x=s*s-P.x-Q.x;
    R.y=s*(P.x-Q.x)-P.y;

return R;
}
```

Firstly...  this line will give you major heartache at some point:

```
s = (P.y - Q.y) / (P.x - Q.x);
```

(***** See below)

Secondly, x and y in P and Q are still unsigned int types.  Therefore, when P.x - Q.x goes negative you will still get large numbers...  that aside, lets walk through the code.

We have:

```
s = (P.y - Q.y) / (P.x - Q.x) = (2 - 4) / (1 - 3) = -2/-2
```

But it won't be -2/-2, it will be 18446744073709551614 / 18446744073709551614 = 1

So, s = 1.

Moving on,

```
R.x=s*s-P.x-Q.x;
R.y=s*(P.x-Q.x)-P.y;
```

We have:

```
R.x=s*s-P.x-Q.x = 1*1-1-3 = 1-1-3 = -3
R.y=s*(P.x-Q.x)-P.y = 1*(1-3)-2 = 1*-2-2 = -4
```

But it won't be -3 and -4, it will be 18446744073709551613 and 18446744073709551612, which is the answer you get.

***** For the Floating Point Exception see above.